# Converting a file into stream

Tags: c#

I have a path which has a list of files.

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(networkpath))
{
  Stream s=file.
}
```

I want to convert the file into Stream.How to proceed further?

Comment: What kind of stream do you need?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help ,got what i wanted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(networkpath))
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can safely read file using FileStream in C#. To be sure the whole file is correctly read, you should call FileStream.Read method in a loop, even if in the most cases the whole file is read in a single call of FileStream.Read method.

First create FileStream to open a file for reading. Then call FileStream.Read in a loop until the whole file is read. Finally close the stream.

```
using System.IO;

public static byte[] ReadFile(string filePath)
{
   byte[] buffer;
   FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath,         FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
      try
     {
        int length = (int)fileStream.Length;  // get file length
       buffer = new byte[length];            // create buffer
        int count;                            // actual number of bytes read
        int sum = 0;                          // total number of bytes read

        // read until Read method returns 0 (end of the stream has been reached)
       while ((count = fileStream.Read(buffer, sum, length - sum)) > 0)
       sum += count;  // sum is a buffer offset for next reading
     }
     finally
     {
         fileStream.Close();
     }
     return buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your file path to suit your code!Add this inside your loop!

```
FileStream fStream = new FileStream(@"c:\file.txt", FileMode.Open);
try
 {
  // read from file or write to file
 }
finally
 {
   fStream.Close();
  }
```